# iOS 10 iMessage App: viewWillTransition(to:with:) giving current size for MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle.compact

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, ios10

I am making an iMessage app. I have implemented `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` in order to resize/rearange the views in my app. When my app's `presentationStyle` is `.expanded` everything works fine. However, in `.comapct` mode, the `size` given is the current size of my view controller, instead of the size it will transition to.

Does anyone now if I am making a mistake, or if it's just an iOS 10 bug?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I can't seem to get this function to fire in my MSMessagesAppViewController at all. How did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Xcode-8.1** has resolved above issue . So update to latest Xcode.